# javascript syntax error within HTML file

Tags: javascript, html

I try to make a button on my webpage once i press it, it will turn up a div box with a google map. But it doesn't work ! it turns up with javascript syntax Error. please helps!

the chrome development tool, turning up with javascript syntax problems: var newDiv ＝document.createElement("div"). 
This is my first time using Google map API to my webpage.

```html
<! DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title> Google book search </title> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
<div id = "input">
 <form>
  
  <input type="button" id="search_button" value="search">


 </form>


</body>
    
</html>

<script > 
var body = document.getElementByTagName("body")[0];
var dosearch= function() {

   var newDiv ＝document.createElement("div")；
   newDiv.setAttribute("id", "map");
   newDiv.style.width="100px";
   newDiv.style.height="100px";
   body.appendChild(newDiv);

}



window.onload=function(){

 console.log("ready")
 var search_button= document.getElementById("search_button");
 search_button.addEventListener("click", dosearch);


}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var map;
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 8
  });
}
</script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDpKAwq-qKxzm-9D1405KCFp7ZTtu_Vimg&callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
```

Comment: For starters, there's no function called `document.getElementByTagName`, so you're going to get an error on your very first line of JavaScript.

Comment: <div id = "input"> , closing tag in missing for the same.

Comment: @David, i think there is no problem with "document.getElementByTagName", after i delete what you mentioned, the error is still there. it says syntax problems:" var newDiv ＝document.createElement("div")". can you copy my code and run it?

Comment: @mansa thanks for telling me, but once i fixed it, the error still occurred.

Answer (score 2):

What is the character at the end of this line?:

```
var newDiv ＝document.createElement("div")；
```

It's not a semi-colon, that looks like this:

```
var newDiv ＝document.createElement("div");
```

That's at least one syntax error.  There could be more hidden in your code.  I don't know where these non-standard characters are coming from, but you should probably just re-type your code with standard characters from scratch.  There could be all sorts of difficult-to-spot invalid characters in here, maybe even non-printable ones.

Answer (score 0):

Find this code, Syntax error are removed. Only error is with Google API now, could be because of missing css in the code you have provided.

```
<! DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> Google book search </title>
    <!--link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"-->
</head>

<body>
<div id = "input">
    <form>
        <input type="button" id="search_button" value="search">
    </form>
</div>

</body>

</html>

<script >
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    var dosearch= function() {

        var newDiv =document.createElement("div");
        newDiv.setAttribute("id", "map");
        newDiv.style.width="100px";
        newDiv.style.height="100px";
        body.appendChild(newDiv);
    };

    window.onload=function(){
        console.log("ready");
        var search_button= document.getElementById("search_button");
        search_button.addEventListener("click", dosearch);
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
            zoom: 8
        });
    }
</script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDpKAwq-qKxzm-9D1405KCFp7ZTtu_Vimg&callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
```

> Error Was :

- Random Special characters in place of = & ;
- getElementsByTagName it is, not getElementByTagName

Comment: thanks for you code !  i think the main problems are still the Javascript sytax error with Google map API, can you help me to fix it ?